# Are most current PDF reader applications (browser, desktop, mobile) able to read PDF 2.0 standard documents?

Tags: pdf, standards, iso

I noticed that, unlike with when Adobe owned the PDF standards, ISO does not make the specifications free to anyone and everyone, but only to paid members. Now I assume that most major software application and plug-in developers would subscribe to ISO, or at least would for this specification, but I don't want to get burned.

We're creating an e-document, and the service that manages acquiring a digital signature said that the user/signor has to be able to open a PDF document created to PDF 2.0 specifications (released August 2017).

Is this an issue, or are all the usual suspects (Adobe Reader, Chrome Plug-ins, Firefox Plug-ins, android and iPhone browser apps) up to speed on this specification?

We're going to put a requirements message and link for free software downloads, so I want to make sure I'm not creating a problem with my "advice" based on assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this an issue, or are all the usual suspects (Adobe Reader, Chrome
>   Plug-ins, Firefox Plug-ins, android and iPhone browser apps) up to
>   speed on this specification?

Versioning in the PDF format is pretty loose, and regardless of the "version" of a particular PDF file, even old versions, it is always possible that a PDF will not "work" properly in any application. The PDF standard is massive, and incorporates a ton of other standards (various fonts, compression algorithms, etc.).

So the answer is, yes this could be an issue, but that is the case for any PDF with any PDF reader (Adobe is not perfect either).

> digital signature said that the user/signor has to be able to open a
>   PDF document created to PDF 2.0 specifications (released August 2017).

I think what is more important for you is perhaps finding out more from your vendor about what exactly they are putting into their digital signatures that make them 2.0 specific. The 2.0 standard definitely improves on Digital Signatures and makes them more robust and reliable.

I suspect that your PDF will render/view fine in any decent PDF reader, but Digital Signature checking/validation would only work with PDF readers supporting 2.0. But most PDF readers ignore digital signatures anyway (since it is just metadata with no bearing on viewing).

Again, getting more info from your vendor would be the best next step. If you find out more you could update your question here.

Comment: "but Digital Signature checking/validation would only work with PDF readers supporting 2.0." - I'm asking if the current versions of the most widely used PDF readers, like Acrobat Reader DC support (or claim to support) PDF 2.0. That's the entire point of my question.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet what exactly do you mean by *support*? Current versions of Adobe Reader will mostly operate according to ISO 32000-2. But it also has some deviating peculiarities which are due to backward support of features from times before there even was an iso pdf standard.

Comment: @mkl - I was using Ryan's language. This isn't that complicated - are they supposed to work with that specification standard? I wanted to know if the fact that ISO does not give free and unfettered access to the standard made any difference on whether end-user viewing apps decided to build to and at least try and be friendly to that specification, or if they are built to the previous specification, 1.7. ISO specifically says 2.0 is not intended as a replacement for 1.7, so I want to be clear about whether this has generally been adopted by the major products. No perfection or guarantee needed.

Comment: @mkl - our vendor told us their documents are being generated using that standard. If the most common viewers are built to handle that standard, and their documents aren't working, then we can tell our vendor they are doing it wrong. If it's not working because the viewer doesn't like or recognize the standard, then we will be recommending a download of a free product that does.... but we have to know whether the most common ones do or not. Your statement about Adobe Reader pretty much answers my question, qualifications included, if you want to offer that as an answer.